# Are bicategories and lax 2-categories the same?

Tags: category-theory, definition, abelian-categories, higher-category-theory

My question is that whether the definition of bicategories is the same as the definition of lax 2-categories.

I heard that they are both week versions of 2-categories.

Are they the same? If not, how do they differ?

I would like to know answers and reference that defines these definitions rigorously.

Thank you.

Comment: I've not heard of a _lax_ 2-category. _Weak_ 2-category is just another name for bicategory, yes. You can find a definition of bicategory [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9810017).

Answer (score 2):

[Leinster](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305049v1.pdf) introduced a *lax bicategory* (def. 3.4.1) -- in an unbiased manner --, which is even more lax than a normal bicategory, in that the coherence morphisms in there are *not* assumed to be *isomorphisms*.